# Get distinct value by using ArrayList#contains() not working

Tags: java

I have a JComboBox call `cmb_user_id`, I get all the user ID from database and save it inside an array of objects called `borrow_data`, but there is some duplicated data in it, so I use `.contains()` method to filter it, below is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> al_id = new ArrayList<>();
cmb_user_id.addItem("Select One");
for(int i = 0; i < borrow_data.length; ++i)
{
    if(!al_id.contains(borrow_data[i].getUser().getId()));
    {
        cmb_user_id.addItem(borrow_data[i].getUser().getId());
        al_id.add(borrow_data[i].getUser().getId());
        System.out.println("Content: " + borrow_data[i].getUser().getId());
    }
}
```

But after all, all data are still saved into `cmb_user_id`, including the duplicated data, my filter doesn't work at all.

Comment: It's hard to understand what's going on with so many variables we don't know about. Please rewrite this as a [mcve] - ideally following Java naming conventions at the same time.

Comment: nope, it returns String

Comment: Your code looks ok and the problem is probably somewhere else - you should follow Jon Skeet's advice.

Comment: but I have explained all 3 variables in my description which are `cmb_user_id`, `borrow_data` and `al_id`, for `al_id`, I have show its declaration on the beginning of the code. @JonSkeet

Comment: I think I see the error/typo, Look at the end of the line ```if(!al_id.contains(borrow_data[i].getUser().getId()));```

Comment: No, you've hardly explained anything - and you haven't shown sample input and actual vs expected output. Basically, you really need to provide a [mcve] - at that point, we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @JornVernee: Good catch. My guess is that the OP would have found that themselves while converting this code *into* a complete example - which is one of the benefits of going through that process. Voting to close as a typo...

Comment: @JonSkeet noted, thanks for your advice and helps.

Comment: @JornVernee I am so careless, that's where the problem is, thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(!al_id.contains(borrow_data[i].getUser().getId()));
```

Has a `;` at the of it, meaning that the following `{...}` will *always* execute.